# What is the preferred way to use interrupt a Java Runnable and run clean up?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interrupt

General question about design here. I have a few threads that need to stay running in the background, basically some database upload/failure handling tasks. The all have the following flow pattern:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean isAlive = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    ....
    public void run() {
        while (isAlive.get()) {

            // do some work here, slightly heavy

            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                // checking Thread.interrupted() as the code above
                // can take a while and interrupt may happen before 
                // it gets here.
                isAlive.setBoolean(false);
                break; // to exit faster
            }

            try { Thread.sleep(sleepTime); } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                isAlive.setBoolean(false);
                break; // to exit faster
            }
        }

        cleanUp(); // e.g. close db connections etc
     }
}
```

Now I would like to be able to interrupt the threads so it can break out of the while loop gracefully and run the `cleanUp()` method.

There are many ways to do this, to list a few:

1. Kick the `Runnables` off in `Threads`, then use the `interrupt()` method:

   ```
   List<Thread> threadList =...
   for (int i < 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
       Thread t = new Thread(new Worker());
       threadList.add(t);
       t.start()
   }

   // later
   for (Thread t : threadList) { t.interrupt(); }
   ```
2. ThreadPoolExecutor, then use `shutdownNow()`:

   ```
   ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ....;
   executor.execute(new Worker()); 

   // some lines else later
   executor.shutdownNow();  // shutdown() doesn't interrupt?
   ```

**What is the way to handle this type of workflow and why?** All ideas welcome.

Comment: `cleanUp();` should be in a `finally` block, unless you want to leave your db connections open when an unexpected exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Over all, I personally think setting `isAlive` to `false` is the cleanest.
According to my knowledge, `interrupt()` is native code, which is a reason itself to stay away from.

Don't forget to set the `boolean` to `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I prefer using AtomicBoolean. Changed code to reflect that. volatile can be a hit to performance in some instances, particularly for frequent accesses.

Comment: In general volatile is a cheaper approach. Atomic variables just have a little more flexibility...  And don't worry about such small performance hits.  It will waist your time and overall has a negligible effect on the overall application.  It's I/O operations and TCP connections that you need to worry about.

Comment: Very true, doesn't matter much here in this case.  <br/> 
Remembered the `volatile` becomes an issue when it's used with `static` and have lots of threads accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are acceptable approaches.  If you have a lot of threads, I'd go with the threadpool approach for the easier management.  If you just have one (maybe two) threads, I would interrupt them individually.

As MouseEvent stated, it would be cleaner to not use the interrupt and use that isAlive variable (which seems to be pointless in your implementation). This, however, implies that you need to close or shutdown each of the instances (still a good approach)

Also, I would surround the entire method in a try-catch-finally statement where you catch the interruption and have the cleanup in the finally clause.

Comment: Edited and added code to change isAlive, I break out of the loop so it exits faster.

try-catch-finally - good idea. Actually is there any performance penalty in putting more code/slower code in the try clause?

Comment: No... There's no performance penalty unless an exception is thrown.  Also the isAlive check is right before the interrupted check.  I'm assuming that both with kick you out at the same time.  If there's any performance gain, it will be far less than a millisecond.

Comment: Added some comments on why I used `Thread.interrupted()`, changed the code a bit to reflect what I meant. Thanks.